# How do I move a station I built to another sector?

Tags: x3-reunion

I have a Solar Power Plant that I built in sector A, and I realized that it isn't exactly doing too well, and I'm looking to move the plant to another sector. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla reunion, there is no way of moving a station.

Luckily, there are several mods that enable you to drag asteroids or repack stations to take you to another sector.

If you do not want to install mods, then there is no way to move your station and the only choice you have is to scuttle it or try to make it profitable somehow.

There is one [glitch](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=259299) that can be used to move mines in X3R2.5, but it doesn't really help you out in this situation:

- Player ship, TL containing mine factory, and desired asteroid are in the same sector
- initiate jumpdrive for player ship (shift j)
- the moment before player ship jumps, deploy mine onto asteroid.
- When you are in your new sector, the mine will be in the same sector you jumped too

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I guess I'll need to get myself some scripts then.